# Minimum vertex degree of a graph divided by 2 is smaller than maximum matching

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Let G be a simple graph. δ(G) is the minimum vertex degree. Prove that if M is the maximum matching, then
δ(G)/2 ≤ |M|.

How to prove this?

Comment: By a greedy construction of the matching.

Comment: If you could give some references, i would like to look into them.

Comment: Keep taking edges to a matching greedily and prove that if you took less than $\delta(G)/2$ then you can take one more.